# Proper way to correct a line mid-debbuging in Python with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, exception, visual-studio-code

Imagine a Python code like this

```
results = long_task(some_arguments)
# this task takes long time
unpolished_task(results)
# this unpolished task can raise unpredicted Exceptions
```

What is the proper way to debug this, without waiting that long time to check how poorly writen the unpolished_task is? I know I could write some tests and save the results object to run unpolished_task later, but is there any way to modify an object after the faulty line is reached and the Exception thrown?
Or, as soon as I see this do I have to accept the execution stops?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2rAX.jpg

Comment: Create some mock `results` & pass that to `unpolished_task`.

Comment: why post an image that is almost all fuzzed out, only post the readable stuff with small bits fuzzed

Comment: the image is not mine, but it reflects the situation when I want to make a change so the program can continue rather than stopping

Comment: @Mart Mont  -In VS Code, the debugging function of the python code tells us which line of code has what type of problem, and once the debugging reports an error to the code, it will jump out of execution, and we can correct the code according to its prompts and then debug again.